# Setting up jupyter-notebook "Binder" in Github

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyterhub

I am trying to obtain the correct GitHub repo or URL from my GitHub repository for "mybinder.org" so that I can create a link in my repository to launch jupyter-notebook from within my repository. I seem to not be able to set things up correctly.

Comment: Serena Bonaretti made [a nice introductory video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owSGVOov9pQ&feature=youtu.be) recently.

Answer (score 2):

I've just made [my first binder repo](https://github.com/lincolnfrias/binder/), a very simple one, you could use it as a model.

The steps are:

1. create a repo in github containing your jupyter notebooks.
2. create a folder called "binder" with a requirements.txt in this repo indicating the packages used in your notebook - or a environment.yml if you use conda instead of pip. See the [examples in the docs](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using.html#id8). Although it is possible to put the requirements.txt in the root folder, creating the "binder" folder reduced the building time from 2-4 minutes to 30s-1 minute.
3. After you create your repo on github, the only thing you need to do is paste its url (e.g, https://github.com/lincolnfrias/binder/) on [mybinder.org](https://mybinder.org/) e click the launch button.

Please, don't hesitate to ask if you need any clarification.

Comment: The placement of the configuration file is not expected to effect the build time. (The suspicion is that "caching" somewhere was responsible for the apparent improvement.) In summary, MyBinder/Binderhub-users should feel free to leave config files in the root directory of the repository or put them in a `binder` sub-directory, if easier.